# Security Privilege Error - Samsung Gear SAP

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm following the Samsung SAP provider/consumer tutorial and I'm getting a security error when I run the connect() method:

```
function connect() {
    console.log("trying to connect");
    document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = 'trying to connect';
    if (SASocket) {
        alert('Already connected!');
        return false;
    }
    try {
        webapis.sa.requestSAAgent(onsuccess, onerror);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("exception [" + err.name + "] msg[" + err.message + "]");
        document.getElementById('errorlabel').innerHTML = "exception [" + err.name + "] msg[" + err.message + "]";
    }
}
```

**js/main.js (74) :exception [SecurityError] msg[The application does not have the privilege to call this method.]**

In my config.xml I have:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://devloper.samsung.com/privilege/accessoryprotocol"/?
```

Do I need anything else e.g. a certificate? I can run the sample projects no problem without my own certificate but do I 
need a certificate if I created the app myself from scratch?

**Update - Solution:**
Two things 
- 1. typo! devloper should be developer
- 2. @Nana Ghartey is also correct - a certificate is needed to test on the device, get this by sending a CSR to Samsung (details on their developer site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to generate a certificate if you want to test your gear consumer widget apps on a real device. You don't need it when running on the emulator

You can find more information about certificates in the Help section of the IDE (Help Contents > Getting Started with **Tizen Wearable > Development Environment > Tizen SDK for Wearable > Certificates**).

Regarding the Privilege issue, the accessory protocol privilege is a public level privilege that allows apps to use SAP to connect and transfer files between gear and host devices. I faced no problems using this privilege.

Perhaps, line 74 in main.js requires a Partner/Platform privilege. Note that install apps on commercial devices, develop apps only with public level privileges. Privileges are categorized into three levels based on their security impact:

**Public**

These privileges are open to all Tizen application developers.

**Partner**

These privileges can only be used by developers registered as partners on the Tizen store.

The developer must be fully identified and permitted by the partner policy of the Tizen Store to use both public and partner level privileges.

**Platform**

These privileges are used in system APIs for managing the Tizen platform.

These privileges are open only to a specific set of Tizen application developers.

For more info check out the Security Architecture [guide](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/?topic=/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/tizen_overview/security.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting the error on both the emulator and the real device, I'll get a certificate and try on the device again.