# Samsung Gear 2 Neo PRIVILEGE_LEVEL_VIOLATION

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I've been working on a project using the Samsung Gear 2 Neo; everything was working fine. The problem started when I got a new computer, about 3 weeks ago, and installed the Tizen IDE and went through the same registration process as I did on my first computer, except now I cannot upload the app I have been working on.
I am able to upload the most basic app, i.e. a black screen with some text. But any app with privilege of accessory protocol fails.  Even though my certificates have a public level (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139075/security-privilege-error-samsung-gear-sap)). 
I have the same setup in the old computer and it works. They are both running on intel, the only difference is the new one runs on 10.10 OS and the old one runs on 10.9.5. Any idea what I am missing on this one?

`<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/accessoryprotocol"/>`

`Error code: PRIVILEGE_LEVEL_VIOLATION
Error message: 
Command: /usr/bin/pkgcmd -i -q -t wgt -p "/opt/usr/apps/tmp/SwatchAppTellartConsumer.wgt"
Management: Refer to Help contents > Getting Started with Tizen > Overview > Privilege.`

Answer (score 2):

Quite Old Topic, yet.. if anyone encounters this post, please refer to:

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/integrated-app-rejection-privileges/201/281069?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~&startPage=2&curPage=4&searchSubId=0000000032

"
Code

```
<tizen:application id="xxxxxxxxxx.yyyyy" package="xxxxxxxxxx" required_version="2.2.1.3"/>
```

TO:
Code

```
<tizen:application id="xxxxxxxxxx.yyyyy" package="xxxxxxxxxx" required_version="2.2"/>
```

Apparantly the privilege checker for samsung seller only allows the following required versions:

```
required_version="2.1"
required_version="2.2"
required_version="2.3"
```

"

In my issue, I had 2.3.1, after removing the ".1" worked fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the same keystore folder you used on the first computer? If you still have the folder, copy it to the new machine and use the same certificate password and device profile password as before. The keys are between your author certificate and the device. It has nothing to do with your PC. You should not have had to reregister for a new certificate.

If you still have the old PC around, it should be in ~/tizen-wearable-sdk-data/keystore or C:\tizen-wearable-sdk-data\keystore.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply Eric. I have tried that and it does not accept the password. I also updated the description, mentioning the difference in the OS systems. The old one IOS 10.9.5 and the new one runs IOS 10.10. Do you think that has something to do?

Comment: I updated last week from Mavericks to Yosemite, so that shouldn't be an issue.  For my testing, I swap out keystores and keys quite often.  The keystore folder contains the author.csr that has to be paired with the author.crt that was created from it.  I'll have one of our developers read your thread and see if they can suggest a course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you need to re-configure author & distributor certificates from inside Tizen SDK. It should be accessible from Window -> Preferences menu item, in Tizen SDK -> Security Profiles section of preferences.

Also make sure that the correct profile is active if you have several profiles.

BTW: On Windows Eclipse now and then resets current security profile to the first one in the list. So the procedure described above is a routine procedure for me now ;)